# Can I put all points in one ability with customized origins?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, ability-scores, dnd-beyond

I was making a mountain dwarf monk in dnd beyond and was able to get my dex up to 19 at level one, using point buy and customized origins (it allowed me to put both initial ASIs on dex). This seems broken to me, is it allowed RAW, or is it a bug in the app?

Comment: I have added the proper system tag for you, since you were talking about DnD Beyond. If for some reason it's not the fifth edition, please change it to an appropriate system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Sort of a bug

You are not allowed to stack the ability scores, and this is documented in the Origin Manager on DnDBeyond. So while it *doesn't validate* that you follow the rules, but it does *say* that you can't stack them. See the picture below:

[image]

This is verbatim taken from the rules for "Customizing Your Origin" in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything. Specifically the section on [Ability Score Increases](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/character-options#AbilityScoreIncreases)

Comment: I think the reason for this bug is that mountain dwarves get +2 from race and +2 from subrace.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. I think it's more general than that. I just tested Kalashtar (no subrace) and the new MoM Changeling (no need for Custom origin). And both could stack their ASIs.